# How to save pdf in download directory rather then current working directory in python?

Tags: python, django

I have written simple pdf splitting code in django using PyPDF2 but it is downloading splitted pdf in same directory(cwd).How do i specify path so that it will downloaad it in Download directory?

**Edit:**
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from .forms import PdfExtractForm
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
 return render(request, 'split/home.html')


def pdf_single_page_extract(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = PdfExtractForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
         f = form.cleaned_data['file']
         print(f.name)
         pdfFileObj = PdfFileReader(f)
         for page in range(pdfFileObj.getNumPages()):
             pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
             pdf_writer.addPage(pdfFileObj.getPage(page))
             output_filename = 'page_{}.pdf'.format(page + 1)
             with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
                 pdf_writer.write(out)
         print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
 else:
     form = PdfExtractForm()

 return render(request, 'split/pdfectract.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you coded? We can then suggest what needs to be changed.

Comment: Hey mate - please post some code, so we can point what can be changed :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
output_filename = 'page_{}.pdf'.format(page + 1)
```

to

```
output_filename = '/home/<username>/Downloads/page_{}.pdf'.format(page + 1)
```

replace  with your computer username. if you want to put user name varible. use this:

```
import os
username = os.getenv('USER')
output_filename = '/home/{}/Downloads/page_{}.pdf'.format(username,page + 1)
```